# SalesForce Spark Delimiter issue

Tags: pyspark, salesforce, aws-glue

I have a glue job, in which am reading table from SF using soql:

```py
df = (
    spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.salesforce")
    .option("soql", sql)
    .option("queryAll", "true")
    .option("sfObject", sf_table)
    .option("bulk", bulk)
    .option("pkChunking", pkChunking)
    .option("version", "51.0")
    .option("timeout", "99999999")
    .option("username", login)
    .option("password", password)
    .load()
)
```

and whenever there is a combination of double-quotes and commas in the string it messes up my table schema, like so:

in source:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000AB | "text with, comma" | 123XX |

read from SF in df :

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000AB | "text with | comma" |

Is there any option to avoid such cases when this comma is treated as a delimiter? I tried various options but nothing worked. And SOQL doesn't accept REPLACE or SUBSTRING functions, their text manipulation functions are, well, basically there aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

All the information I'm giving need to be tested. I do not have the same env so it is difficult for me to try anything but here is what I foud.

When you check the [official doc](https://github.com/springml/spark-salesforce), you find that there is a field `metadataConfig`. The documentation of this field can be found here : https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/bi_dev_guide_ext_data_format.pdf

On page 2, `csv format`, it says :

> If a field value contains a control character or a new line the field value must be contained within double quotes (or your
> fieldsEscapedBy value). The default control characters (fieldsDelimitedBy, fieldsEnclosedBy,
> fieldsEscapedBy, or linesTerminatedBy) are comma and double quote. For example, "Director of
> Operations, Western Region".

which kinda sounds like you current problem.

By default, the values are `comma` and `double quotes`, so, I do not understand why it is failing. But, apparently, in your output, it keeps the double quotes, so, maybe, it considers only simple quote.
You should try to enforce the format and add in you code :

```py
    .option("metadataConfig", '{"fieldsEnclosedBy": "\"", "fieldsDelimitedBy": ","}')
# Or something similar - i could'nt test, so you need to try by yourself
```

Comment: thanks, I tried something similar and I checked the solution you proposed and unfortunately, it didn't work. Thanks though for the hint.

Comment: @RedMosquitoo I wish I could have helped you but your env/config is so specific ... I know salesforce is used in my compagny but I never tried to connect directly with Spark. The data transfer is done using ODI. Good luck with your problem.